# Using two sources of data in a HandlebarsJS template

Tags: templates, handlebars.js

I have a Handlebars template that uses a data source containing a list of names in alphabetical order. Now I need to amend this template so I can display a list of buttons (one for each letter) across the top of the template. Then when the user clicks on a button it filters the list of names in the template, but still show all the buttons for each letter across the top.

Is it possible to pass the two forms of data to the one template or can I filter data loaded in a template after is has loaded?

Stephen

Answer (score 0):

I would create an object that has the properties for each letter of the alphabet.  The values for those keys would be arrays containing each name.  From there, you can nested `{{#each}}` blocks to loop through them without having to create any additional helpers.

HTML:

```
<script id="hbs">
    {{#each this}}
        {{@key}}
        <ul>
            {{#each this}}
                <li>{{this}}</li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Javascript:

```
var names = ['alfa', 'beta', 'bob', 'cat', 'man', 'dog', 'etc'];
var context = {};

(function(names) {
    var first = "";

    for (var i = 0, j = names.length; i < j; i++) {
        first = names[i][0];

        if (!context.hasOwnProperty(first)) {
            context[first] = [];   
        }

        context[first].push(names[i]);
    }

})(names);

var template = Handlebars.compile($('#hbs').html());
var html = template(context);
$('body').append(html);
```

Here's a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sja7th6k/) of the concept.  Good luck :)